# Вырезать из строки выражение

Tags: python

Как можно из следующей строки получить tests?

```
str = "http://tt-tests:123/wd/hub" (без str[10:str.rfind(':')])
```

т.е. необходимо чтобы из этой строки получилось на выходе **tests**.

например: print(str[10:str.rfind(':')])

Comment: Как понятно, что вытащить нужно именно ``tests``, а не ``tt-t``, например?

Comment: да, нужно вытащить после дефиса все до :

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Прпробуйте так:

```
import re
from urllib.parse import urlparse

def f(url, pat2del=r'[^-]*-'):
    t = urlparse(url).netloc.partition(':')[0]
    return re.sub(pat2del, '', t)
```

Тесты:

```
In [166]: f('http://tt-tests:123/wd/hub')
Out[166]: 'tests'

In [167]: f('http://tt-tests.com/wd/hub')
Out[167]: 'tests.com'

In [168]: f('http://tt-tests.co.uk:80/wd/hub')
Out[168]: 'tests.co.uk'

In [169]: f('http://www.something.co.uk:80/wd/hub')
Out[169]: 'www.something.co.uk'

In [170]: f('http://www.abc-something.co.uk:80/wd/hub')
Out[170]: 'something.co.uk'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
YOURSTRING = "http://tt-tests:123/wd/hub" (без str[10:str.rfind(':')])
answer(re.findall(r'.*\/\/\w+-(\w+):\w+\/.*', YOURSTRING)[0])
print(answer)
```

регулярки удобно [здесь](https://regex101.com/) тестить

Answer (score 1):

Без особых изысков

```
str[str.index('-') + 1:str.index(':', str.index('-') + 1)]
```

---

```
str.split('-')[1].split(':')[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

https://ideone.com/nYoKDs

```
import re

str = "http://tt-tests:123/wd/hub"
print(re.sub(r"://[^:/]*[:/]?", "://", str))
```

Comment: не то , получается на выходе - http://123/wd/hub

Comment: Так ты это и просил.

Comment: нет, мне нужно на выходе - tests

Comment: Тогда критерии понятно объясни.